# How to store references to types in Nim?

Tags: types, nim-lang

Can you store the `type` of an object in Nim, similiar to using the `Class` object in Java?
For example, I would like to achieve something like this:

```
let myType = someObject.type
```

Assuming that `.type` would return the `type` of the object. If that is possible, I'd also like to create objects that can store `HashSets` of types, ideally using generics to limit the types that can be used:

```
type System = object
    includes: HashSet[type[Component]]
    excludes: HashSet[type[Component]]
```

Or is this something that is currently impossible in Nim?

Comment: what do you want to use these types for, once you store them?

Comment: @JakubDóka i'd like to check if a sequence contains those types.
for example, given the `System` object from above and a `seq[Component]`, i'd like to map the sequence to a `HashSet[type[Component]]` and then check if it includes all the `includes` and none of the `excludes` of the `System`.

Comment: you can convert types into unique ids easily, would that help?

Comment: @JakubDóka already thought about using something like this, if it exists. could you point me in the right direction? i only found the typetraits module, which did not offer that functionality.
anyway, does this mean that there's no way to work with the types themselves?

Comment: you can work with types but only on compile time. There is a neat and simple solution form asigning ids to types. I can push an answer with it if you want.

Comment: hmm compile time won't really do it for me, unfortunately.
i could easily create an id field for `Component` and just assign ids for all subtypes manually, but that's kinda cumbersome and not extensible as they MUST be unique. so if there's a way to automatically generate ids for types and make sure they're unique, it would be nice.
not sure if you should post it as answer, though, as it does not really answer the question.

Comment: If you're using inheritance it's a completely different game, you do have access to rtti.  But it sounds like a variant would be a better fit, it comes with a typeid already baked in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Storing types

the `typedesc` type is not available at runtime, so it's not possible to store a type as is.

the naive solution would be to just take the string representation of the type:

```
let myType = $(myObject.type)
```

but this might not work the way you want if you have type aliases

```
type
  A = seq[int]
```

here `$A != "seq[int]"` even though the two are otherwise identical and interoperable, similarly `float64` and `float`

https://github.com/yglukhov/variant has already implemented these edge cases, so let's leverage that:

`nimble install variant`, then, roughly:

```
import variant
let myTypeId = someObject.getTypeId # the hash of a string representation
myTypeSet.incl myTypeId #put it in your hash set
```

This concludes the functional portion of this answer, that which extensively follows deals with how to statically error when trying to include an unwanted type.

---

---

#### Limiting which types may be included

If you're only interested in limiting inheritable types this is a bit easier than if you want to limit with typeclasses.

```
import variant,sets
type
  TypeSetBase = HashSet[TypeId]
  TypeSet*[T] = distinct TypeSetBase

proc initTypeSet*[T](): TypeSet[T] =
  TypeSetBase(result).init()

proc incl*[T](ts: var TypeSet[T], x: typedesc[T]) =
  TypeSetBase(result).incl getTypeId(x)

proc contains[T](ts: TypeSet[T],x: typedesc): bool =
  TypeSetBase(ts).contains getTypeId(x)

type
  Foo = object of RootObj
  Bar = object of Foo
  Baz = object of Foo
  Qux = object

var includes = initTypeSet[Foo]()

includes.incl Bar
includes.incl Baz

assert Bar in includes
assert Baz in includes
assert not(Foo in includes)
#includes.incl Qux #static error
```

---

For the general case this is harder.  Typeclasses won't get us there, as one can't instantiate a `TypeSet[int | float]`

Here's my solution, using a macro to do the boilerplate for us. this is self-contained.

```
import macros,variant,sets
type TypeSetBase = HashSet[TypeId]

macro TypeSet*(name,cls,rhs:untyped) =
  let tynm = ident("TypeSet_" & cls.repr)
  let initnm = ident("init_" & cls.repr)
  
  result = quote do:
    when not declared(`tynm`):
      type `tynm` = distinct TypeSetBase
      proc `initnm`():`tynm` =
        TypeSetBase(result).init()
      proc incl*(ts: var `tynm`, x:typedesc[`cls`]) =
        TypeSetBase(ts).incl getTypeId(x)
      proc contains*(ts: `tynm`, x:typedesc):bool =
        TypeSetBase(ts).contains getTypeId(x)
    var `name` = `initnm`()
```

```
import sugar # just nicer for procs

var x{.TypeSet.}:SomeNumber | proc

x.incl float
x.incl (int)->int
x.incl ()->string

#x.incl string 
# static error:
# type mismatch: got <TypeSet_SomeNumber | proc, type string>

assert float in x
assert ((int)->int) in x
assert (proc():string) in x
```

this doesn't get you your `System` type yet but i'm out of time for the moment.

Comment: too bad it's not possible to work with types directly, but your proposed solutions seem like a really good workaround. thank you :)

Comment: you're welcome.  In general I don't want the overhead of dragging around all that typeinfo, so I do appreciate that Nim doesn't do it by default. But I acknowledge that when you do need it/can afford the overhead it should be simpler.

Comment: I also realise I haven't addressed your need (post question) to do this after the types are all in a seq! That's a different kettle of fish, and I still think you should be using variants.

Answer (score 2):

Nim does not support reflection like java does. You can manipulate with types only on compile time. What you can do though is convert all needed types to ids at compile times and use ids instead. Now how do we generate ids? Actually nim has wery simple and neat solution for this that uses global macro data.

```
import macrocache

type TypeID* = uint16

const nextTypeID = CacheCounter("nextTypeID")

converter typeID*(T:typedesc): TypeID =
    const id = nextTypeID.value
    static:
        inc nextTypeID
    return id.TypeID

when isMainModule:
    assert float == 0
    assert float == 0
    assert int == 1
    assert float64 == 0
    assert string == 2
    assert (float, int) == 3
```

Each time typeID is compiled for a type it stores cached counter state in a constant within the compiled body. Static block will run each time function compiles so each time you pass a different type, counter increases.

Comment: also a valid solution for my problem, although it is a bit unpredictable as those ids can change

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit types generics takes, you can use type class.
https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#generics-type-classes

For example:

```
# Generic type only takes string or int.
type
  Foo[T: string or int] = object
    x: T

var
  a: Foo[string]
  b: Foo[int]

#var c: Foo[float] # Compile error

# Generic proc takes any type of arguments excepts float and tuple.
proc bar[T: not (float or tuple)](x: T) = discard

bar(1)
bar("a")
#bar(1.1)     # Compile error
#bar((1, 1))  # Compile error
```

Comment: thanks, but my question is not really about generics. the only reason i mentioned them was that it would be great if the `type` type supported them, should it exist.

Comment: i suggest you to delete this answer to not confuse other users. If mine is not right either i will delete it too.

Comment: It's often the case that a non-accepted answer is extremely helpful to later visitors, please don't remove good answers!